# Ripple effect in StackLayout or Grid after click

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid, effect, ripple, stacklayout

How to achieve an effect of smooth change of background color in StackLayout or Grid after the click? If we create a button it has this effect out of the box - I showed that in an attached gif. The same is for ViewCell in ListView. It also has this ripple effect of changing background color after a click. But how to achieve that for StackLayout or Grid?[image]

How to achive this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Thought you said that ViewCell  has the ripple effect of changing background color after a click .You can put the **Stacklayout** or **Grid** in the listview which has only one ViewCell.

> in xaml

```
<StackLayout>


    <ListView x:Name="listView">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <ViewCell>

                    <StackLayout>

                      <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Content}"/>

                    </StackLayout>

                </ViewCell>

            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

> in code behind

```
public class Data
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}


public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public ObservableCollection<Data> MySource { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = this;



        MySource = new ObservableCollection<Data>()
        {
          new Data() {Content="Click Me" },
        };

        listView.ItemsSource = MySource;

    }

}
```

**Solution 2:**

You can use the package [TouchView](https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/TouchEffect) from nuget

Add nuget package to your Xamarin.Forms .netStandard/PCL project and to your platform-specific projects (iOS and Android)

> iOS: add TouchViewRenderer.Initialize() line to your AppDelegate
>   (preserve from linker)

```
using TouchEffect.iOS;
namespace YourApp.iOS
{
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            TouchViewRenderer.Initialize();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

> in xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourApp"
             xmlns:touch="clr-namespace:TouchEffect;assembly=TouchEffect"
             x:Class="App11.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <touch:TouchView
            RegularBackgroundColor="LightGray"
            PressedBackgroundColor="Gray"
            PressedOpacity="1"       

            PressedAnimationDuration="100"
            RegularAnimationDuration="100"
            Padding="10, 5"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Completed="Handle_TouchCompleted"
           >

            <Label Text="Click Me" 
                   TextColor="Black" 
                   FontSize="30"/>

        </touch:TouchView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

> in code behind

```
private void Handle_TouchCompleted(TouchEffect.TouchView sender, TouchEffect.EventArgs.TouchCompletedEventArgs args)
 {
    // do something you want        
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
BotonRefrescar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#32CEF9");
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200), () =>
    {
        //do something
        BotonRefrescar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#32BBF9");
        return false;
    }
);
```

Comment: Why does your answer just has a bunch of code with 0 explanation?